# Imputing missing value based on filtering result of another column

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | x |
| A | y |
| A | z |
| A | x |
| A | NaN |
| A | x |
| A | x |
| A | x |
| B | y |
| B | y |
| B | z |
| B | y |
| B | NaN |
| B | y |
| B | x |
| B | x |

I have to impute missing values in C2 , the imputation should be such that if the missing values corresponding C1 column is A, then filter the datset by A and find the mode of C2 and replace the missing value, similarly for B.

In the above example it should be x for first missing value and y for second missing value

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | x |
| A | y |
| A | z |
| A | x |
| A | x |
| A | x |
| A | x |
| A | x |
| B | y |
| B | y |
| B | z |
| B | y |
| B | y |
| B | y |
| B | x |
| B | x |

Tried this, not sure if this is the best way

```
for i in df['c1'].unique(): 
  df[(df['c1']==i) & (df['c2'].isnull())]['c2'] = df[df['c1']==i]['c2'].mode()[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas `groupby` and `transform` methods. This maps the groupwise mode to the index of the original dataframe.

```py
df['C2']=df.groupby('C1').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().index[0]))['C2']
df
```

The output is:

[image: output_of_transformation]